# Django best practices: should I use a ListView or a normal view if I want to display also a list of categories and a search form?

Tags: python, django, listview

I'm reading [Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django 1.8](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) where it is suggested to always use generic class based views.

So I'm trying to convert a page where I display a list of objects (`def objects_listing(request)`) into a class derived from ListView (`class ObjectsList(ListView)`).

The problem is that my view not only is needed to display a list of objects but also:

- A search form to filter these objects (which links on the same view);
- A list of categories of objects.

The solution appears to be to override the function `get_context_data` to provide additional context to the template (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)).

My question is: is it still considered best practice to use ListView in this case? Or should I stick to a normal view instead? Which are the pros and cons of these approaches?

---

Pros of `ListView`:

- The paginator works automatically in the ListView if you provide a `page` argument with GET. No need to pass it to the paginator object and to check for crazy user input: non-int values and non-existing pages are handled automatically. This appears to be compatible with [DiggPaginator](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/773/), also.

Cons of `ListView`:

- No access to self.request (or self.session) outside of methods.

Comment: `self` does not exist outside of methods in any other class, not only in `ListView`

Comment: Indeed... which is a point in favor of a normal view function, where you have easier access to context and request. Unless somebody can explain how and why we should use class views when these features are needed.

Comment: for example: where is the method to retrieve the request object? Should I do this in get_context_data? In that case it would be extremely unclear and subjective to anybody reading my code. Why is there no "get_request_data"?

Comment: I think a pro is that you can define a `get` (for listing) and a `post` method (for your filtering form) in the same view using the same url. And you can access to the request and session in both, get and post methods.

Comment: Why would you need `self.request` outside a method? Will you write logic outside a method? You can access `request` inside any class-view's method.

Comment: would you suggest to override the get method should my filtering form use get instead of post? I think this should be a separate question, though... Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, I said that you can use POST for your form and GET for your listing objects, in the same view but in separated methods (HTTP verbs)

Comment: I understand, but the use of GET for the filtering form is compulsive for my app: I need "copypastable" links to search queries (quite a common use-case). So I was asking if overriding the GET method is considered bad-design or not (although we're going a bit off-topic)...

Comment: Oh, I understand. Yes I think is normal override methods GET to catch params and filter list, or you could use some external project, such as [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). But this should be another question. This is a good question and I hope to get more points of view.

Comment: thanks for your feedback and help. With a little bit of research, I've found that overriding the get_queryset method can also be a good idea for filtering. Example: http://www.pythondiary.com/blog/Oct.31,2012/really-starting-love-djangos-class-based-views.html

Comment: took a break and posted a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701703/django-get-search-form-in-listview-class-view